# How to make checkbox check by default in yii while using single form for create and update

Tags: forms, yii

I am using single form for creating and updating a form.I need checkbox checked by default in the following  form

```
<div class="row" style='float:left;;margin-left:5px'>
        <?php echo '<span for="label" style="margin-bottom:5px;font-size: 0.9em;font-weight: bold;">Label</span><br />'; ?>
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'label_name',array('value'=>1,'uncheckValue'=>0,'checked'=>'checked','style'=>'margin-top:7px;')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'label_name'); ?>
    </div>
```

i am using above code to achieve the same purpose i am not getting the result as expected. While updating the form it shows checked even though  it was unchecked

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i got solution i worked with code itself please have a look

```
<div class="row" style='float:left;;margin-left:5px'>
        <?php echo '<span for="label" style="margin-bottom:5px;font-size: 0.9em;font-weight: bold;">Label</span><br />'; ?>
        <?php echo $form->checkBox($model,'label_name',array('value'=>1,'uncheckValue'=>0,'checked'=>($model->id=="")?true:$model->label_name),'style'=>'margin-top:7px;')); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'label_name'); ?>
    </div
```

Answer (score 4):

A better solution would be to set the value in the controller:

```
public function actionCreate() {
    $model = new ModelName();

    if (isset($_POST[$model])) {
        // ... save code here
    }
    else {
        // checkboxes for label 'label_name' with value '1' 
        //   will be checked by default on first load
        $model->label_name = true; // or 1
    }

    $this->render('create', array(
        'model' => $model,
    ));
}
```

Or better still, in the `afterConstruct()` function in the model:

```
protected function afterConstruct() {

    parent::afterConstruct();

    $this->label_name = true; // or 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the below link

http://www.bsourcecode.com/2013/03/yii-chtml-checkboxlist

I hope the link is useful.

Comment: The link you specified opens a "Page not Found" error

Comment: Please remove the .html from redirected URL

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to set the default value in the model:

```
public $label_name = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to keep the checkbox checked for both create and update. checked=checked will serve the purpose on create form but , on updating you have to handle it through code